# what is the difference between "Request.newMeRequest" and "new http Request("

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to get some FB data from my android app.

I see there are two ways of doing this:

A)

```
new Request(session,"/me/interests", null, HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        /* handle the result */
                    }
                }
            ).executeAsync();
```

B)

```
Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
```

is one of them deprecated?

how do i ask for specific node\edge (e.g. "/me/interests") in the second signature?

Does it gives me all the node ready made as long as I asked for the proper permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request.newMeRequest is simply a wrapper around new Request(session, "/me"). It's a convenience method.

If you want to ask for anything else, you need to construct it yourself, probably using the newGraphPathRequest method - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Request/#newGraphPathRequest

So for the "me/interests" example above, you would do something like:

```
Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "me/interests", new Request.Callback() {...})
  .executeAsync();
```

Comment: how can you ask about a specific edge in "me" that way?

Comment: edited my response, but I'm not sure if that's what you were asking.

Answer (score 1):

1) As specified in the docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Request/), none of them is deprecated.

2) You can't ask for a specific node/edge, because it is already configured to retrieve a users profile.

3) You get a `GraphUser`and a `Response` as a return (in `onComplete`).

Most likely, `newMeRequest` will call `new Request` internally.

Comment: i'm confused. permissions, graphObject, nodes

Comment: ` it is already configured to retrieve a users profile.` use mean "me/profile" node or "public_profile" permission?